# PHP removing html tags from string

Tags: php, html

I have string:

```
<p justify;"="">Vers­lo cent­rai Lie­tu­vos ne­kil­no­ja­mo­jo turto plėt­ros aso­cia­ci­jos kon­kur­se  ...</p>
```

and want  want remove tag

```
<p justify;"=""></p>
```

my code:

```
$content = strip_tags($text, '<p>');
```

but i get empty string: `string(0) ""` , what I do wrong ?

Answer (score 19):

Try to put it like that

```
$content = strip_tags($text);
```

Or you can do it with regular expression like that:

```
$content = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $text);
```

By this `$content = strip_tags($text, '<p>');` you are allowing the `<p>` tag in the string.

For more info see the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: It doesn't work.  I just tested it on my box and that first unmatched quote is the problem.  Even that goofy semi-colon works with strip_tags, as long as he didn't have that first quote...

Comment: @MihaiIorga Ya agree to you.It may be typo mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Since the HTML is poorly formated you probably need to either write your own regexp to remove tags or clean up the HTML before trying to remove tags.

You could try this to remove everything that "looks like" a tag:

```
$str = preg_replace("/<.*?>/", " ", $str);
```

Comment: Really? Why would wordpress use an unmatched quote?

Comment: This works for me. strip_tags only converts tags to other characters

Answer (score 4):

Since your HTML is not properly formatted you could choose a `preg_replace()` approach:

```
$text = '<p justify;"="">Vers­lo cent­rai Lie­tu­vos ne­kil­no­ja­mo­jo turto plėt­ros aso­cia­ci­jos kon­kur­se ... </p>';
$content = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $text); 
var_dump($content);
// string(108) "Vers­lo cent­rai Lie­tu­vos ne­kil­no­ja­mo­jo turto plėt­ros aso­cia­ci­jos kon­kur­se ... "
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/7givAwHA)

On [strip_tags() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) it says: *Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.*

Also second parameter is for `$allowable_tags`.

Answer (score 4):

This will remove every thing - tags, ascii, line breaks but pure text:

```
strip_tags(preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/','',str_replace(array("&nbsp;","\n","\r"),"",html_entity_decode($YOUR_STRING,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'))));
```

Comment: This worked for me after removing `'UTF-8'` as second parameter needs to be integer

Answer (score 1):

This will replace all html tags, 
https://regex101.com/r/jM9oS4/4

```
preg_replace('/<(|\/)(?!\?).*?(|\/)>/',$replacement,$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

From PHP 7.4.0 the strip_tags() alternatively accepts an array with allowable tags,

then this:

```
<?php

$html = '<div id="my-div"><p>text<strong><a href="#link"></a></strong></p></div>';

echo strip_tags($html, ['p', 'a']); //accept p and a tags
```

Return this:

```
<p>text<a href="#link"></a></p>
```

Note that only the disallowed tags have been removed.