# Regex to match placeholders that contain HTML within them

Tags: php, regex

I have placeholders that users can insert into a WYSIWYG editor (which contains HTML code). Sometimes when they paste from apps like Word etc it injects HTML within them.

Eg: It pastes `%<span>firstname</span>%` instead of `%firstname%`.

Here is an example of my regex code:

```
$html = '

    <p>%firstname%</p>

    <p>%<span>firstname</span>%</p>

    <p>%<span class="blah">firstname</span>%</p>

    <p>%<span><span>firstname</span></span>%</p>

    <p>%<span><span><span>firstname</span></span></span>%</p>

    <p>%<span class="blah"><span>firstname</span></span>%</p>

    <div>other random <strong>HTML</strong> that needs to be preserved.</div>

';

preg_match_all(
    '/\%(?![0-9])((?:<[^<]+?>)?[a-zA-z0-9_-]+(?:[\s]?<[^<]+?>)?)\%/U', 
    $html, 
    $matches
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => %firstname%
            [1] => %firstname%
            [2] => %firstname%
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => firstname
            [1] => firstname
            [2] => firstname
        )

)
```

As soon as there is more than one span inside the placeholder it doesn't work. I'm not quite sure what to adjust in my regex.

```
/\%(?![0-9])((?:<[^<]+?>)?[a-zA-z0-9_-]+(?:[\s]?<[^<]+?>)?)\%/U
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: A dupe of [*PHP removing html tags from string*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309077/php-removing-html-tags-from-string)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My problem is I need to get the strings using regex.

Comment: With a regex, you can only match the balanced number of tags, but you would have to loop over the matches and process them further or use `preg_replace_callback` with [this](https://regex101.com/r/iF1uQ4/4) and use `strip_tags` anyway inside the anonymous function. The problem is that you cannot access a  substring captured from within a subroutine call. That is why this type of task should not really be done with a regex (in general, it is rather cumbersome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex. It should help you out!

`/\%(?![0-9])(?:<[^<]+?>)*([a-zA-z0-9_-]+)(?:[\s]?<\/[^<]+?>)*\%/U`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a parser and the `textContent` property if it is a `WYSIWYG` editor anyway:

```
<?php

$html = '
    <p>%firstname%</p>
    <p>%<span>firstname</span>%</p>
    <p>%<span class="blah">firstname</span>%</p>
    <p>%<span><span>firstname</span></span>%</p>    
    <p>%<span><span><span>firstname</span></span></span>%</p>
    <p>%<span class="blah"><span>firstname</span></span>%</p>
    <div>A cool div with %firstname%</div>
    <span>And a very neat span with %firstname%</span>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

# query only root elements here
$containers = $xpath->query("/*");
foreach ($containers as $container) {
    echo $container->textContent . "\n";
}
?>
```

This outputs `%firstname%` a couple of times, see [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/gL8IXZ).

Comment: Thanks @Jan but I cannot presume that all placeholders will be in <p> tags. They could be in divs, table cells, anywhere due to the WYSIWYG allowing the user to edit the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a regex for this? You could have simply used [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) here.

Try this:

```
echo strip_tags($html);
```

Comment: Like I mentioned, it's WYSIWYG editor so I need to preserve HTML code outside placeholders. I'll make my post clearer.